# VS2015 missing frameworks not being installed (universal apps)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015 (Community).

I just created a brand new universal app, but when I run the app it hangs on installing framework elements.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug x86 ------ 
1>  App1 -> D:\Development\TV Show Manager\main\App1\bin\x86\Debug\App1.exe 
2>------ Deploy started: Project: App1, Configuration: Debug x86 ------  
2>Updating the layout...  2>Copying files: Total <1 mb to layout... 
2>Checking whether required frameworks are installed...  
2>Framework: Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0/x86, app package version 1.0.23117.0 is not currently installed.  
2>Framework: Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug/x86, app package version 14.0.23019.0 is not currently installed.  
2>Installing missing frameworks...
```

Anybody happens to know how to solve this problem?

PS: restart visual studio / rebuilds doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with "Emulators for Windows Mobile 10.0.10240" Uninstalling  and reinstalling seems to fix the issue. Can you deploy to a device?

Comment: Tried it already, didn't work and gave up. I'll wait a bit until its a bit more mainstream so that the microsoft fixes things and try again

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by installing the missing appx through Powershell as admin. Example for the ones I needed:

```
Add-AppxPackage "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime\1.1\AppX\x86\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx"
Add-AppxPackage "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Kits\10\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\14.0\Appx\Debug\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx"
```

There are lots of appx in the ExtensionSDK folder. Just install those you need and it will work.

In your case, replace 1.1 with 1.0 in the first string.